# MySQL help on nested queries and joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: **Product**, **PC**, **Laptop** with the following schema.

```
Product (maker, model, type)
PC (model, speed, ram, hd, price)
Laptop (model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
```

How can I retrieve the *model number* and *price* of all products made by a *maker A?*

I've attempted this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Product 
 WHERE maker = "A" 
  JOIN type.model,type.price;
```

and this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Product 
  JOIN Laptop ON Laptop.model;
```

...but without any luck.

**Edit**: If I want to make it more general, how could I display model and price of any product made by the manufacturer A, not just Laptop and PC?

Comment: Disregarding the first attempt, the second needs to show how the `laptop` relates to the `product` table -- you've only got 1/2 the JOIN criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(SELECT product.maker, laptop.model, laptop.price
 FROM Product 
 INNER JOIN laptop ON product.model = laptop.model
 WHERE product.maker = "A" )
UNION
(SELECT product.maker, pc.model, pc.price
 FROM Product 
 INNER JOIN pc ON product.model = pc.model
 WHERE product.maker = "A" )
```

Comment: You should use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/10/05/union-vs-union-all-performance/

Comment: If I want to make it more general, how could I display model and price of any product made by the manufacturer A, not just Laptop and PC?

Comment: @BluePonyInc. you would may want to consider changing your database structure. As it stands you'd have to add another union for each product type. My guess is that you want a single product table with a column for the product type (which itself is defined in another table). You may want to post a question on how to refactor your database...

Comment: This is probably a homework - selfstudy question. I can't remember which online SQL tutorial-questions site I've seen this structure.

Comment: Mr E, thanks. Ypercube I am reading as a self-study this textbook "A First Course in Database Systems", 3rd Edition by Ullman and Widom.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT model, price FROM Product INNER JOIN PC ON Product.model = PC.model WHERE maker = "A"
UNION
SELECT model, price FROM Product INNER JOIN Laptop ON Product.model = Laptop.model WHERE maker = "A"
```

Answer (score 2):

Some points:

1. strings in SQL are single quotes not double quotes.
2. you should consider using UNION ALL.
3. you should join PC to PRODUCT and LAPTOP to PRODUCT on MODEL.

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT PC.MODEL, PC.PRICE
FROM   PC
JOIN   PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.MODEL = PC.MODEL AND PRODUCT.MAKER = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT LAPTOP.MODEL, LAPTOP.PRICE
FROM   LAPTOP
JOIN   PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.MODEL = LAPTOP.MODEL AND PRODUCT.MAKER = 'A'
```

Comment: And thirdly, you should use `JOIN` nowadays, 20 years after 1992.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some mysql [join tutorials](http://mysqljoin.com/joins/inner-join-tutorial/) so you'll know how to do this on your own.

I assume that `product.model` references both `pc.model` and `laptop.model`. You probably want query like this, using [mysql `IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT IF(laptop.price IS NULL, pc.price, laptop.price) AS `price`, product.model
FROM product
LEFT JOIN pc ON (pc.model = product.model AND product.type = 'pc')
LEFT JOIN laptop ON (laptop.model = product.model AND product.type = 'laptop')
GROUP BY product.id
HAVING price IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: And I guess you meant: `product.type = 'pc'`, not `.model`

Comment: @ypercube thanks, fixed... About "good design"... When field `product.model` references two different tables you cannot use foreign key and that seems bad idea to me.

Comment: The FKs are from `pc` to `product` and from `laptop` to `product` in these cases.

Comment: @ypercube that's good design and implementation, but doing it by `model` referencing two different tables = bad design and bad implementation (or maybe good design and bad implementation)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. I meant something like Option 3 in @gbn's answer here: [Pet-Cat-Dog example](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9752/nulls-in-a-composite-primary-key-sql-server/9754#9754). If `PC` and `Laptop` tables had a `type` column, then the two patterns would be identical.